# Map - Not able to Drag and drop at a specific point in the Map

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Map - Not able to Drag and drop at a specific point in the Map

Map is Similar to the Map given in the link :
http://beta.findtoilet.dk/?term=2&lat=55.678937&lng=12.575738&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap

In the Map we have a PegMan and i need to drag and drop the pegman to the Orange mark.

Below is my code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                WebElement pegmanoption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title,'Drag Pegman onto the map to open Street View') and contains(@style,'position: absolute;')]"));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title,'Drag Pegman onto the map to open Street View') and contains(@style,'position: absolute;')]")));
WebElement mapname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@role,'button') and contains(@style,'position: absolute;')]"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(pegmanoption).clickAndHold().moveToElement(mapname).release().perform(); = Tried this and this doesnt work...

Tried by using offset and works very rarely: 
builder.moveToElement(pegmanoption).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(290, 0).release().perform();

Tried with :
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(pegmanoption)
.moveToElement(mapname)
.release(mapname)
.build();
dragAndDrop.perform();

Basically no matter what iam trying the drag and drop is not working :

HTML:

PegMan HTML:
<div class="gm-svpc" dir="ltr" title="Drag Pegman onto the map to open Street View" controlwidth="40" controlheight="40" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px; width: 40px; height: 40px; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;), default; touch-action: none; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2023%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M16.6%2038.1h-5.5l-.2-2.9-.2%202.9h-5.5L5%2025.3l-.8%202a1.53%201.53%200%2001-1.9.9l-1.2-.4a1.58%201.58%200%2001-1-1.9v-.1c.3-.9%203.1-11.2%203.1-11.2a2.66%202.66%200%20012.3-2l.6-.5a6.93%206.93%200%20014.7-12%206.8%206.8%200%20014.9%202%207%207%200%20012%204.9%206.65%206.65%200%2001-2.2%205l.7.5a2.78%202.78%200%20012.4%202s2.9%2011.2%202.9%2011.3a1.53%201.53%200%2001-.9%201.9l-1.3.4a1.63%201.63%200%2001-1.9-.9l-.7-1.8-.1%2012.7zm-3.6-2h1.7L14.9%2020.3l1.9-.3%202.4%206.3.3-.1c-.2-.8-.8-3.2-2.8-10.9a.63.63%200%2000-.6-.5h-.6l-1.1-.9h-1.9l-.3-2a4.83%204.83%200%20003.5-4.7A4.78%204.78%200%200011%202.3H10.8a4.9%204.9%200%2000-1.4%209.6l-.3%202h-1.9l-1%20.9h-.6a.74.74%200%2000-.6.5c-2%207.5-2.7%2010-3%2010.9l.3.1L4.8%2020l1.9.3.2%2015.8h1.6l.6-8.4a1.52%201.52%200%20011.5-1.4%201.5%201.5%200%20011.5%201.4l.9%208.4zm-10.9-9.6zm17.5-.1z%22%20style%3D%22isolation%3Aisolate%22%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20opacity%3D%22.7%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M5.9%2013.6l1.1-.9h7.8l1.2.9%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592c%22/%3E%3Cellipse%20cx%3D%2210.9%22%20cy%3D%2213.1%22%20rx%3D%222.7%22%20ry%3D%22.3%22%20style%3D%22isolation%3Aisolate%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592c%22%20opacity%3D%22.5%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M20.6%2026.1l-2.9-11.3a1.71%201.71%200%2000-1.6-1.2H5.699999999999999a1.69%201.69%200%2000-1.5%201.3l-3.1%2011.3a.61.61%200%2000.3.7l1.1.4a.61.61%200%2000.7-.3l2.7-6.7.2%2016.8h3.6l.6-9.3a.47.47%200%2001.44-.5h.06c.4%200%20.4.2.5.5l.6%209.3h3.6L15.7%2020.3l2.5%206.6a.52.52%200%2000.66.31l1.2-.4a.57.57%200%2000.5-.7z%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M7%2013.6l3.9%206.7%203.9-6.7%22%20style%3D%22isolation%3Aisolate%22%20fill%3D%22%23cf572e%22%20opacity%3D%22.6%22/%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2210.9%22%20cy%3D%227%22%20r%3D%225.9%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" aria-label="Street View Pegman Control" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); pointer-events: none;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M22%2026.6l-2.9-11.3a2.78%202.78%200%2000-2.4-2l-.7-.5a6.82%206.82%200%20002.2-5%206.9%206.9%200%2000-13.8%200%207%207%200%20002.2%205.1l-.6.5a2.55%202.55%200%2000-2.3%202s-3%2011.1-3%2011.2v.1a1.58%201.58%200%20001%201.9l1.2.4a1.63%201.63%200%20001.9-.9l.8-2%20.2%2012.8h11.3l.2-12.6.7%201.8a1.54%201.54%200%20001.5%201%201.09%201.09%200%2000.5-.1l1.3-.4a1.85%201.85%200%2000.7-2zm-1.2.9l-1.2.4a.61.61%200%2001-.7-.3l-2.5-6.6-.2%2016.8h-9.4L6.6%2021l-2.7%206.7a.52.52%200%2001-.66.31l-1.1-.4a.52.52%200%2001-.31-.66l3.1-11.3a1.69%201.69%200%20011.5-1.3h.2l1-.9h2.3a5.9%205.9%200%20113.2%200h2.3l1.1.9h.2a1.71%201.71%200%20011.6%201.2l2.9%2011.3a.84.84%200%2001-.4.7z%22%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20fill-opacity%3D%22.2%22/%3E%26quot%3B%3C/svg%3E" aria-label="Pegman is on top of the Map" style="display: none; height: 30px; width: 30px; position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); pointer-events: none;"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2040%2050%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M34-30.4l-2.9-11.3a2.78%202.78%200%2000-2.4-2l-.7-.5a6.82%206.82%200%20002.2-5%206.9%206.9%200%2000-13.8%200%207%207%200%20002.2%205.1l-.6.5a2.55%202.55%200%2000-2.3%202s-3%2011.1-3%2011.2v.1a1.58%201.58%200%20001%201.9l1.2.4a1.63%201.63%200%20001.9-.9l.8-2%20.2%2012.8h11.3l.2-12.6.7%201.8a1.54%201.54%200%20001.5%201%201.09%201.09%200%2000.5-.1l1.3-.4a1.85%201.85%200%2000.7-2zm-1.2.9l-1.2.4a.61.61%200%2001-.7-.3L28.4-36l-.2%2016.8h-9.4L18.6-36l-2.7%206.7a.52.52%200%2001-.66.31l-1.1-.4a.52.52%200%2001-.31-.66l3.1-11.3a1.69%201.69%200%20011.5-1.3h.2l1-.9h2.3a5.9%205.9%200%20113.2%200h2.3l1.1.9h.2a1.71%201.71%200%20011.6%201.2l2.9%2011.3a.84.84%200%2001-.4.7zM34%2029.6l-2.9-11.3a2.78%202.78%200%2000-2.4-2l-.7-.5a6.82%206.82%200%20002.2-5%206.9%206.9%200%2000-13.8%200%207%207%200%20002.2%205.1l-.6.5a2.55%202.55%200%2000-2.3%202s-3%2011.1-3%2011.2v.1a1.58%201.58%200%20001%201.9l1.2.4a1.63%201.63%200%20001.9-.9l.8-2%20.2%2012.8h11.3l.2-12.6.7%201.8a1.54%201.54%200%20001.5%201%201.09%201.09%200%2000.5-.1l1.3-.4a1.85%201.85%200%2000.7-2zm-1.2.9l-1.2.4a.61.61%200%2001-.7-.3L28.4%2024l-.2%2016.8h-9.4L18.6%2024l-2.7%206.7a.52.52%200%2001-.66.31l-1.1-.4a.52.52%200%2001-.31-.66l3.1-11.3a1.69%201.69%200%20011.5-1.3h.2l1-.9h2.3a5.9%205.9%200%20113.2%200h2.3l1.1.9h.2a1.71%201.71%200%20011.6%201.2l2.9%2011.3a.84.84%200%2001-.4.7z%22%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20fill-opacity%3D%22.2%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M15.4%2038.8h-4a1.64%201.64%200%2001-1.4-1.1l-3.1-8a.9.9%200%2001-.5.1l-1.4.1a1.62%201.62%200%2001-1.6-1.4L2.3%2015.4l1.6-1.3a6.87%206.87%200%2001-3-4.6A7.14%207.14%200%20012%204a7.6%207.6%200%20014.7-3.1A7.14%207.14%200%200112.2%202a7.28%207.28%200%20012.3%209.6l2.1-.1.1%201c0%20.2.1.5.1.8a2.41%202.41%200%20011%201s1.9%203.2%202.8%204.9c.7%201.2%202.1%204.2%202.8%205.9a2.1%202.1%200%2001-.8%202.6l-.6.4a1.63%201.63%200%2001-1.5.2l-.6-.3a8.93%208.93%200%2000.5%201.3%207.91%207.91%200%20001.8%202.6l.6.3v4.6l-4.5-.1a7.32%207.32%200%2001-2.5-1.5l-.4%203.6zm-10-19.2l3.5%209.8%202.9%207.5h1.6V35l-1.9-9.4%203.1%205.4a8.24%208.24%200%20003.8%203.8h2.1v-1.4a14%2014%200%2001-2.2-3.1%2044.55%2044.55%200%2001-2.2-8l-1.3-6.3%203.2%205.6c.6%201.1%202.1%203.6%202.8%204.9l.6-.4c-.8-1.6-2.1-4.6-2.8-5.8-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-2.8-4.9a.54.54%200%2000-.4-.3l-.7-.1-.1-.7a4.33%204.33%200%2000-.1-.5l-5.3.3%202.2-1.9a4.3%204.3%200%2000.9-1%205.17%205.17%200%2000.8-4%205.67%205.67%200%2000-2.2-3.4%205.09%205.09%200%2000-4-.8%205.67%205.67%200%2000-3.4%202.2%205.17%205.17%200%2000-.8%204%205.67%205.67%200%20002.2%203.4%203.13%203.13%200%20001%20.5l1.6.6-3.2%202.6%201%2011.5h.4l-.3-8.2z%22%20fill%3D%22%23333%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M3.35%2015.9l1.1%2012.5a.39.39%200%2000.36.42h.14l1.4-.1a.66.66%200%2000.5-.4l-.2-3.8-3.3-8.6z%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M5.2%2028.8l1.1-.1a.66.66%200%2000.5-.4l-.2-3.8-1.2-3.1z%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592b%22%20fill-opacity%3D%22.25%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M21.4%2035.7l-3.8-1.2-2.7-7.8L12%2015.5l3.4-2.9c.2%202.4%202.2%2014.1%203.7%2017.1%200%200%201.3%202.6%202.3%203.1v2.9m-8.4-8.1l-2-.3%202.5%2010.1.9.4v-2.9%22%20fill%3D%22%23e5892b%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M17.8%2025.4c-.4-1.5-.7-3.1-1.1-4.8-.1-.4-.1-.7-.2-1.1l-1.1-2-1.7-1.6s.9%205%202.4%207.1a19.12%2019.12%200%20001.7%202.4z%22%20style%3D%22isolation%3Aisolate%22%20fill%3D%22%23cf572e%22%20opacity%3D%22.6%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M14.4%2037.8h-3a.43.43%200%2001-.4-.4l-3-7.8-1.7-4.8-3-9%208.9-.4s2.9%2011.3%204.3%2014.4c1.9%204.1%203.1%204.7%205%205.8h-3.2s-4.1-1.2-5.9-7.7a.59.59%200%2000-.6-.4.62.62%200%2000-.3.7s.5%202.4.9%203.6a34.87%2034.87%200%20002%206z%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M15.4%2012.7l-3.3%202.9-8.9.4%203.3-2.7%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592b%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M9.1%2021.1l1.4-6.2-5.9.5%22%20style%3D%22isolation%3Aisolate%22%20fill%3D%22%23cf572e%22%20opacity%3D%22.6%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M12%2013.5a4.75%204.75%200%2001-2.6%201.1c-1.5.3-2.9.2-2.9%200s1.1-.6%202.7-1%22%20fill%3D%22%23bb3d19%22/%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%227.92%22%20cy%3D%228.19%22%20r%3D%226.3%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M4.7%2013.6a6.21%206.21%200%20008.4-1.9v-.1a8.89%208.89%200%2001-8.4%202z%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592b%22%20fill-opacity%3D%22.25%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M21.2%2027.2l.6-.4a1.09%201.09%200%2000.4-1.3c-.7-1.5-2.1-4.6-2.8-5.8-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-2.8-4.9a1.6%201.6%200%2000-2.17-.65l-.23.15a1.68%201.68%200%2000-.4%202.1s2.3%203.9%203.1%205.3c.6%201%202.1%203.7%202.9%205.1a.94.94%200%20001.24.49l.16-.09z%22%20fill%3D%22%23fdbf2d%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M19.4%2019.8c-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-2.8-4.9a1.6%201.6%200%2000-2.17-.65l-.23.15-.3.3c1.1%201.5%202.9%203.8%203.9%205.4%201.1%201.8%202.9%205%203.8%206.7l.1-.1a1.09%201.09%200%2000.4-1.3%2057.67%2057.67%200%2000-2.7-5.6z%22%20fill%3D%22%23ce592b%22%20fill-opacity%3D%22.25%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" aria-label="Street View Pegman Control" style="height: 40px; width: 40px; position: absolute; transform: translate(-60%, -45%); pointer-events: none; display: none;"></div></div>

Point where the red dot lies HTML for that:

<div role="button" tabindex="0" style="width: 27px; height: 43px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: -14px; top: -43px; z-index: 1;"><img alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap1" style="width: 27px; height: 43px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;"><map name="gmimap1" id="gmimap1"><area log="miw" coords="13.5,0,4,3.75,0,13.5,13.5,43,27,13.5,23,3.75" shape="poly" tabindex="-1" title="" style="cursor: pointer; touch-action: none;"></map></div>
```

Any Leads ...

Comment: Where is the red mark ?

Comment: its orange mark here country Conditori La Glace - @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

following things are not possible in selenium

1. Map drawings,
2. Image Comparison

if you are drawing through co-ordinates, your display size should be always same.

Comment: This is not drawings or comparison it is just dragging and dropping and works some times and coordinates will be the same in my case since it is only one test case which i have implemented....if there are any solutions pls suggest -@Jayanth Bala

Comment: Only option worked for me is, i made everything to constant. like 
contant your screen size. 
contant your timing of actions.
(
execution started at 0th min
map loaded at 1st min
start dragging at 2nd min
)  always our code should start dragging at same time. it will work as same always. if sometimes load takes much time, your element alignment would not same. make it constant for every execution